# Implementing a join function that is being passed 3 arguments

Tags: javascript, join, syntax, concatenation

I'm looking to complete this exercise fLet's write a function called join that works just like the built-in join, but using reduce!

```js
Let's write a function called join that works just like the built-in join, but using reduce! If you're unfamiliar with the built-in version of join, this is how it works:

["the", "quick", "brown", "fox"].join(" "); // => "the quick brown fox"
["one", "two", "three"].join(":"); // => "one:two:three"
Part One: First, write a function called joinWith that takes three arguments: the string to join onto, the string that will be joined, and a separator. That is, it should work like this:

function joinWith(onto, next, separator) {
  // YOUR CODE HERE
}
joinWith("the quick", "brown", " "); // => "the quick brown"
joinWith("one:two", "three", ":"); // => "one:two:three"
Part Two: Now, using joinWith and reduce, write join:

function join(array, separator) {
  // YOUR CODE HERE
}
join(["the", "quick", "brown", "fox"], " "); // => "the quick brown fox"
join(["one", "two", "three"], ":"); // => "one:two:three"
```

and I have written the following code:

```js
var joinWith = function(start, toAdd, separt){

  return reduce(arguments, function(start, toAdd){
    return start + separt + toAdd; 
     
  }, " ");
}
```

However I'm not sure why I'm getting the following as a result.

```js
joinWith("one: two", "three", ":");
" :one: two:three::"
```

Can someone tell me what is happening here and how to I remove the separator from the front of the string and the areas where the separator should not show up.

I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Your code does not run, `reduce` is undefined (did you mean to use `Array.prototype.reduce` but forgot the array in front?). Why not just `return start + separt + toAdd;`? Also why did you use `var joinWith` when you already have the function declaration and the place where you should put code? PS: this looks like homework.

Comment: Why the `reduce()` call.  Why isn't the whole body of the function just `return start + separt + toAdd`?

Comment: You don't show your `reduce()` implementation, but in a general sense using `reduce()` on `arguments` doesn't make sense for this purpose because that would process all of the arguments in order *including* `separt`, plus you've told it to start with `" "` as its first value. Add a `console.log(start, toAdd)` inside your `reduce()` callback and you'll see why you're getting that result.

Comment: @ASDFGerte This is a part of a group of exercises that I'm trying to do.  the reduce function is one that I implemented from the underscore library.

Comment: @jfriend00 that makes sense to do. However the exercise asks me to use reduce. Maybe I should turn the first and second arguments into an array?

Comment: @IvonneTerrero - Then you need to describe the EXACT requirements of the exercise and you need to show us what the `reduce()` function is, because though we could guess, a standalone `reduce()` function is not a standard part of Javascript.  The only point I can see for using `reduce()` is to process an arbitrary number of arguments, not precisely 3 arguments.

Comment: @jfriend00 I see. Sorry for the confusion . I will add the entire description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What's currently happening:**

You don't show your `reduce()` function's implementation, but assuming it works in the same manner as the standard `Array.prototype.reduce()` then your output can be explained as follows:

`arguments` is an array-like object with these values:

```
["one: two", "three", ":"]
```

When you call `reduce()` on `arguments`, it visits each item in turn as follows:

1st iteration: `start` is `" "`, from the last argument to `reduce()`, and `toAdd` is `"one: two"`. From that iteration you return the string `" :one: two"`.

2nd iteration: `start` is `" :one: two"` (the return value from the previous iteration), and `toAdd` is `"three"`, and you return `" :one: two:three"`.

3rd iteration: `start` is `" :one: two:three"` (the return value from the previous iteration), and `toAdd` is `":"` and you return `" :one: two:three::"`

**What you should do:**

You know the function has three arguments, so just use:

```
function joinWith(start, toAdd, separt) {
  return start + separt + toAdd;
}
```

**But you *really* want to use `reduce()`:**

Well it's really the wrong tool for the job when your specification is to join only two strings, but if you must, you want to use it on all but the last argument to `joinWith()` - noting that as follows that lets you pass an arbitrary number of strings to join as long as the separator is the last argument:

```js
var joinWith = function(){
  if (arguments.length < 3) return arguments[0];
  var separt = arguments[arguments.length-1];
  return reduce(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0,-1), function(start, toAdd){
    return start + separt + toAdd;
  }); // note: do not pass an initial value
}
    
console.log(joinWith("one: two", "three", ":"));
console.log(joinWith("one","two","three","four","five",":"));
console.log(joinWith("a","b","c","d","e",", "));
console.log(joinWith("x","y"));
    
// Dodgy simulation of your reduce() function for demo purposes only: 
function reduce(arr, cb) {
  return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arr, cb);
}
```